# JavaFX: Adding a new tab from a tab controller

Tags: java, javafx, tabs, javafx-8

I am trying to make it such that I can create a new tab for my TabPane from within another tab but I am having some difficulty. Currently I have the TabPane set up in the "main-window.fxml" with the corresponding MainWindowController. I have a tab within this TabPane which, via fx:include, displays "mainTab.fxml" to the scene graph, controlled by MainTabController. Now from within the "mainTab" I want a button to be able to add an additional tab to the TabPane, but since this is requires a reference to the TabPane in "main-window", I have created a static method in "main-window". When the run the code below I get a NullPointerException on this line in the MainWindowController:

```
mainTabPane.getTabs().add(new Tab(team.getTeamName()));
```

Could someone please tell me as to why it is giving this exception and how I can begin to work around it?

main-window.fxml:

```xml
<TabPane fx:id="mainTabPane">
    <tabs>
        <Tab fx:id="mainTab" text="Main" closable="false">
            <fx:include source="mainTab.fxml" fx:id="mainWindowTab" alignment="CENTER"/>
        </Tab>                
    </tabs>
</TabPane>
```

mainTab.fxml (the event handler for the button):

```
@FXML
public void handleSubmit() {
    String teamName = teamNameTextField.getText();
    Roster roster = rosterComboBox.getValue();
    int startWeek = spinner.getValue();
    Team newTeam = new Team(teamName, startWeek, roster);
    TeamData.addTeam(newTeam);
    MainWindowController controller = new MainWindowController();
    controller.createTeamTab(newTeam);

}
```

MainWindowController:

```
public class MainWindowController {

    @FXML
    private TabPane mainTabPane;

    public void createTeamTab(Team team) {
        mainTabPane.getTabs().add(new Tab(team.getTeamName()));

    }
}
```

Comment: "since this is requires a reference to the TabPane in "main-window", I have created a static method": this doesn't really make sense. You've identified the problem: you don't have a reference to the tab pane in the controller for the main tab. The solution is not to make anything static: the solution is to provide a reference to the `MainWindowController` instance to the `MainTabController`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Instead of making anything static then I can provide an instance of the `MainWindowController` to the `MainTabController` and run the method from there but I still get the same error. Sorry if I am missing something obvious here but I'm still very new to programming!

Comment: [Edit] your question to show that version. (Note: you have to provide the actual controller to `MainTabController`, not just *any* instance of `MainWindowController`.)

Comment: I created an instance of `MainWindowController` which would be why it still isn't working. What do you mean when you say "provide the actual controller to `MainTabController`"? Thanks

Comment: In the `MainWindowController`'s `initialize()` method you would do something like `mainWindowTabController.setWindowController(this);`, with the obvious methods and fields defined.

Comment: Hi James, forgive me if I am being dumb but what are the obvious methods and fields? I'm still struggling to understand how I can reference the TabPane from `MainWindow` in the `handleSubmit` method in the `MainTabController`

Comment: You would need a `mainWindowTabController` field in `MainWindowController` and a `setWindowController` method in `MainTabController` (or whatever the controller class is for `mainTab.fxml`).... Again, if you [edit] your question to show the attempt where you don't make anything static, it would be easier to help you.

Comment: I've updated the question to creating an instance of MainWindowController which is still wrong. Sorry I should have been more specific before, what would the setWindowController method entail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you are not calling `createTeamTab(...)` on the controller: you are calling it on another instance of `MainWindowController` that you created. (The fields annotated `@FXML` are initialized in the controller instance by the `FXMLLoader` when the FXML is loaded: for fairly obvious reasons they will not be set to the same values in arbitrary other instances of the same class.) You need to get a reference to the controller you are using for the main tab, and pass it a reference to the main controller.

You didn't tell us the class name for the controller of `mainTab.fxml`: I will assume it is `MainTabController` (so just change it to whatever class name you actually use).

In `MainWindowController`, do:

```
public class MainWindowController {

    @FXML
    private TabPane mainTabPane;

    @FXML
    // fx:id of the fx:include with "Controller" appended
    private MainTabController mainWindowTabController ; 

    public void initialize() {
        mainWindowTabController.setMainWindowController(this);
    }

    public void createTeamTab(Team team) {
        mainTabPane.getTabs().add(new Tab(team.getTeamName()));

    }
}
```

and then in `MainTabController` do

```
public class MainWindowController {

    private MainWindowController mainWindowController ;

    public void setMainWindowController(MainWindowController mainWindowController) {
        this.mainWindowController = mainWindowController ;
    }

    @FXML
    public void handleSubmit() {
        String teamName = teamNameTextField.getText();
        Roster roster = rosterComboBox.getValue();
        int startWeek = spinner.getValue();
        Team newTeam = new Team(teamName, startWeek, roster);
        TeamData.addTeam(newTeam);
        mainWindowController.createTeamTab(newTeam);

    }

}
```

Comment: ahh yes this is exactly the solution I was looking for thank you! I don't think I fully understood how the controllers worked and that I had to reference THE instance rather than any old instance, but this clears that up! Much appreciated